# fscanf while-loop never runs

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

I'm working on a project, and I can't seem to figure out why a piece of my function for finding prime numbers won't run.  Essentially, I want to code to first check the text file log for any previously encountered prime numbers, but no matter what I put for the while-loop containing fscanf(), it seems like my code never enters it.

```
int filePrime(int a) {
int hold = 0;
FILE *fp = fopen("primes.txt", "a+");

if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Error while opening file.");
    exit(2);
}

/*
the while loop below this block is the one with the issue.
on first run, it should skip this loop entirely, and proceed
to finding prime numbers the old-fashioned way, while populating the file.
instead, it is skipping this loop and proceeding right into generating a
new set of prime numbers and writing them to the file, even if the previous
numbers are already in the file
*/

while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &hold) == 1){ 
    printf("Inside scan loop.");
    if (hold >= a) {
        fclose(fp);
        return 1;
    }
    if (a % hold == 0) {
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
}

printf("Between scan and print.\n");

for (; hold <= a; hold++) {
    if (isPrime(hold) == 1) {
        printf("Printing %d to file\n", hold);
        fprintf(fp, "%d\n", hold);
        if (hold == a)
            return 1;
    }
}

fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

I have tried all sorts of changes to the while-loop test.
Ex. != 0, != EOF, cutting off the == 1 entirely.

I just can't seem to get my code to enter the loop using fscanf.

Any help is very much appreciated, thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Is there any data in `primes.txt`?  Is the first 'field' a number?  Are you sure?  Consider using `fgets()` to read a line — so you can print it, and then scan it with `sscanf()` instead of `fscanf()`.

Comment: prime.txt is either a brand new file, created by fopen(), or filled with integers from the fprintf() further down the code.  I also tried running it seeded with the initial prime "2", but nothing changed.

Comment: `if (hold == a) return 1;` does not first close `fp`.

Comment: why not look see what fscanf is returning.

Comment: Good catch!  I'll fix that up :) However, it still doesn't change the issue that I am seeing with the code never entering the fscanf while-loop.

Comment: Where does the `"a+"` mode leave the current file pointer?  At the start or at the end of the file?  If you do an `fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET)` before the `fscanf()` loop, does that change anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987613/fscanf-while-loop-never-runs/36988028#comment61530262_36987613), I asked where the `"a+"` mode leaves the current position?

On Mac OS X 10.11.4, using `"a+"` mode opens the file and positions the read/write position at the end of file.

Demo code (`aplus.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char source[] = "aplus.c";
    FILE *fp = fopen(source, "a+");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s\n", source);
    }
    else
    {
        int n;
        char buffer[128];
        fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
        while ((n = fscanf(fp, "%127s", buffer)) == 1)
            printf("[%s]\n", buffer);
        printf("n = %d\n", n);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Without the `fseek()`, the return value from `n` is -1 (EOF) immediately.
With the `fseek()`, the data (source code) can be read.

One thing slightly puzzles me: I can't find information in the POSIX [`fopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html) specification (or in the C standard) which mentions the read/write position after opening a file with `"a+"` mode.  It's clear that write operations will always be at the end, regardless of intervening uses of `fseek()`.

POSIX stipulates that the call to [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) shall use `O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_APPEND` for `"a+"`, and `open()` specifies:

> The file offset used to mark the current position within the file shall be set to the beginning of the file.

However, as [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux) [notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987613/fscanf-while-loop-never-runs/36988028#comment61530778_36988028) (thanks!), the C standard explicitly says:

> #### Annex J Portability issues
>
> #### J.3 Implementation-defined behaviour
>
> #### J.3.12 Library functions
>
> …
>   Whether the file position indicator of an append-mode stream is initially positioned at
>   the beginning or end of the file (7.21.3).
>   …

So the behaviour seen is permissible in the C standard.

The manual page on Mac OS X for `fopen()` says:

> - `"a+"` —  Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does not exist.  The stream is positioned at the end of the file.  Subsequent writes to the file will always end up at the then current end of file, irrespective of any intervening fseek(3) or similar.

This is allowed by Standard C; it isn't clear it is fully POSIX-compliant.

Comment: Note: C11 §J.3.12 Portability issues "Whether the file position indicator of an append-mode stream is initially positioned at the beginning or end of the file (7.21.3)."

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to see.  I am on OS X 10.11.4.  Is it exclusive to this version of OS X, or something I should be looking out for moving forward?  In all the documentation I checked, it told me "a+" should open the read position at the beginning, and the write at the end.

Comment: @ConCat: See the updates to the answer, and the comment from chux.  It is implementation defined; it can vary between platforms.  Using the explicit `fseek()` is sensible since the behaviour can vary.  Note that between a read and a write operation, or between a write and a read, you need to use a positioning function (such as `fseek()`) anyway.